# How to add an alert statement to JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to show an alert when the computation is done. It is inside my JQuery script.

Here's my code:

```
<script language="javascript">
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#payable').change(function() {
        var str = $('#payable').val();
        var value = $('#value').val();
        if (str == "1 Week") {
           var result = value / 6;
           $("#deduc").val(result);
        } else if(str == '1 Month'){
           var result = value / 24;
           $("#deduc").val(result);
        } else if(str == '2 Months'){
           var result = value / 48;
           $("#deduc").val(result);
        }
    })
})
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try something, for instance after the last `else if` statement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken to add an alert after the function is done you can just add one line before the end of your script

```
$('#payable').change(function() {
    var str = $('#payable').val();
    var value = $('#value').val();
    if (str == "1 Week") {
       var result = value / 6;
       $("#deduc").val(result);
    } else if(str == '1 Month'){
       var result = value / 24;
       $("#deduc").val(result);
    } else if(str == '2 Months'){
       var result = value / 48;
       $("#deduc").val(result);
    }
    alert("Completed!");
})
```